# IEqualityComparer error

Tags: c#, abstract-class, iequalitycomparer

I'm following a tutorial from C# 7.0 in a Nutshell and getting an error that I can't fix.  The way that I understood the error is that the method needs to be an abstract method, which I also tried, but that didn't resolve the error.  And I thought abstract classes allowed non-abstract methods in them.

Here is the code:

```
public abstract class EqualityComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer, IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public abstract bool Equals(T x, T y);
    public abstract int GetHashCode(T obj);

    bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y);
    int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj);

    public static EqualityComparer<T> Default { get; }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
'EqualityComparer<T>.IEqualityComparer.Equals(object, object)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It allows non-abstract methods, but non-abstract methods must have code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yous have to *implement* the methods (explicit interface implementation makes the methods efficiently `private` which prevent them from being `abstract`: you can't declare, say, `abstract bool IEqualityComparer.Equals...` ), e.g.:

```
bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y) {
  if (x is T && y is T)
    return this.Equals((T)x, (T)y); // known types, run Equals
  else
    return object.Equals(x, y);     // unknown type(s), run default Equals 
}

int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj) {
  if (obj is T)
    return this.GetHashCode((T)obj);
  else
    return null == obj ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `abstract` class can have `abstract` methods/properties and `non-abstract` methods/properties.  Sub-classes of `abstract` classes must implement all methods/properties marked `abstract` in the base class

The `abstract` methods/properties do not need to be implemented in the base-class.  However, any methods/properties you have in the base class that are not marked `abstract` must be implemented (i.e. have code).

Remember, the sub-classes *don't* need to implement the methods/properties not marked `abstract`; someone needs to implement them.

The error you are getting is for the second `Equals` overload - this one:

```
bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y);
```

You also need to provide a body for:

```
int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj);
```

Note that it isn't `abstract` and doesn't have an implementation/body.  It needs to look like:

```
int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj)
{
    //your code goes here - returning an int
}
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is in the abstract class.  Not in the subclass.

Comment: @rds80 you need to add abstract to method declaration if you want it to be abstract. the class being abstract doesn't make all methods automatically abstract.

Comment: I'm not talking about any sub-classes.  In the base/abstract class, you need to provide an implementation for any methods not declared `abstract`.  Put dummy bodies on those methods (for example, just put `return 0;` for both), and your code should compile.